# Swift : Rotate a layer around a centre point

Tags: swift

I have a Layer created using CAShape Layer centred at (x,y). I wanted to know how to rotate the same, around its centre.

[image: t]

So in the above picture, how do we rotate the pointer? CGAffineTransform ? or CABasicAnimation, what has to be used and how as well(syntax of the same).

Answer (score 0):

Set your UIElement's layer "Horizontally in Container" & "Vertically in Container" first in your storyboard. Then, add following code.

```
let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0)
rotateAnimation.duration = 1.0
rotateAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
yourlayer.addAnimation(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
```